# Запись и чтение в NSUserDefaults

Tags: nsuserdefaults, json

Добрый день.
В своем приложении я получаю данные о пользователе с сервера ВКонтакте. С получением и распарсиванием JSON вроде все в порядке, но при попытке записать и прочитать полученный JSON в `NSUserDefaults` (`currentUser`) получаю следующее:

> **INFO**:  -[UserLogic setFirstName:lastName:photo:broadcast:] 2014/04/17 18:29:32:252 | firstName: (
>     "\U042e\U043b\U0438\U044f"
> )
>
> **INFO**:  -[UserLogic setFirstName:lastName:photo:broadcast:] 2014/04/17 18:29:32:262 | User info: (null) (null)

Код следующий:

```
NSJSONSerialization *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
NSJSONSerialization *user = [[json valueForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"user"];

[[UserLogic instance] setFirstName:[user valueForKey:@"first_name"]
                          lastName:[user valueForKey:@"last_name"];
```

реализация метода `setFirstName:lastName:`

```
-(void)setFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName  
{
     DDLogCInfo(@"firstName: %@", firstName);
     [currentUser setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
     [currentUser setObject:lastName forKey:@"lastName"];
     [currentUser synchronize];
     DDLogCInfo(@"User info: %@ %@", [currentUser stringForKey:@"firstName" ], [currentUser stringForKey:@"lastName"]);
}
```

Comment: Проверьте типы данных [user valueForKey:@"first_name"] и [user valueForKey:@"last_name"]. Это точно NSString? Для этого: 
`NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[user valueForKey:@"first_name"] class]));` и/или
`NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[user valueForKey:@"last_name"] class]));`

Comment: Благодарю, szarajewski, оказалось NSArray.